# C# console app to subscribe to Chuck Norris API

Tags: c#, beginner, console, json.net, httpclient

I'm a newbie when it comes to programming. I'm working on a console app that subscribes to ChuckNorris JSON API and displays the results.

I believe I took into account all possible scenarios. Do you guys think I missed anything? Or something can be done better?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using JokesApp;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static List<string> results = new List<string>();
        static char key;
        static ConsolePrinter printer = new ConsolePrinter();
        static Dictionary<string, string> keyValuePairs = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        static string category = string.Empty;
        static List<string> listofcategories = new List<string>();
        static List<string> listofcategoriesactaul = new List<string>();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int numberofjokes;
            printer.Value("Press ? to get instructions.");
            key = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
            while (true)
            {
                printer.Value("Press c to get categories").ToString();
                printer.Value("Press r to get random jokes").ToString();
                key = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
                if (key == 'c')
                {
                    getCategories();
                    Printcategories();
                }
                if (key == 'r')
                {

                    printer.Value("Want to specify a category? y/n").ToString();
                    key = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
                    if (key == 'y')
                    {
                        getCategories();
                        Printcategories();
                        printer.Value("Enter a category from above ").ToString();
                        category = Console.ReadLine();

                        if (listofcategoriesactaul.Contains(category))
                        {
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            printer.Value("Category  does not exists, please reenter correct category from the list ").ToString();
                            bool iscorrect = false;
                            category = Console.ReadLine();
                            if (listofcategoriesactaul.Contains(category))
                            {
                                iscorrect = true;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                iscorrect = false;
                            }
                            while (!iscorrect)
                            {
                                printer.Value("Category  does not exists, please reenter correct category from the list ").ToString();

                                category = Console.ReadLine();
                                iscorrect = listofcategoriesactaul.Contains(category);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        printer.Value("How many jokes do you want? (1-9)").ToString();

                        while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out numberofjokes))
                        {
                            Console.Write("This is not valid input. Please enter an integer value: between 1 to 9 \n");
                        };

                        GetRandomJokes(category, numberofjokes);
                        keyValuePairs.Clear();
                        foreach (var data in results)
                        {
                            string[] jokeval =
                                data.Split(new string[] { "JokeData" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

                            if (!keyValuePairs.ContainsKey(jokeval[1]))
                            {
                                keyValuePairs.Add(jokeval[1], jokeval[0]);
                            }
                        }
                        results.Clear();
                        foreach (var item in keyValuePairs.Values)
                        {
                            results.Add(item);
                        }
                        PrintResults();
                    }
                    if (key == 'y')
                    {
                        printer.Value("How many jokes do you want? (1-9)").ToString();

                        while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out numberofjokes))
                        {
                            Console.Write("This is not valid input. Please enter an integer value: between 1 to 9 \n");
                        };

                        GetRandomJokes(category, numberofjokes);
                        keyValuePairs.Clear();
                        foreach (var data in results)
                        {
                            string[] jokeval =
                                data.Split(new string[] { "JokeData" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

                            if (!keyValuePairs.ContainsKey(jokeval[1]))
                            {
                                keyValuePairs.Add(jokeval[1], jokeval[0]);
                            }
                        }
                        results.Clear();
                        foreach (var item in keyValuePairs.Values)
                        {
                            results.Add(item);
                        }
                        PrintResults();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        printer.Value("How many jokes do you want? (1-9)").ToString();

                        while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out numberofjokes))
                        {
                            Console.Write("This is not valid input. Please enter an integer value: between 1 to 9 \n");
                        };
                        GetRandomJokes(category, numberofjokes);
                        keyValuePairs.Clear();

                        foreach (var data in results)
                        {
                            string[] jokeval =
                                data.Split(new string[] { "JokeData" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

                            if (!keyValuePairs.ContainsKey(jokeval[1]))
                            {
                                keyValuePairs.Add(jokeval[1], jokeval[0]);
                            }
                        }
                        results.Clear();
                        foreach (var item in keyValuePairs.Values)
                        {
                            results.Add(item);
                        }
                        PrintResults();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private static void PrintResults()
        {
            foreach (string joke in results)
            {
                printer.Value(joke + "\n").ToString();
            }
        }

        private static void Printcategories()
        {
            try
            {
                string category = listofcategories[0];
                category = category.Replace('[', ' ');
                category = category.Replace(']', ' ');
                category = category.Trim();

                foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(category, "\"([^\"]*)\""))
                    listofcategoriesactaul.Add(match.ToString().Replace('"', ' ').Trim());
                foreach (string categories in listofcategoriesactaul)
                {

                    printer.Value(categories.Replace('"', ' ').Trim()).ToString();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.Message.ToString();
            }
        }

        private static void GetRandomJokes(string category, int number)
        {
            new JsonFeed("https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random", number);
            results.Clear();
            Console.Write("Please Wait....");
            //while (true)
            //{

            //}
            for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
            {
                results.Add(JsonFeed.GetRandomJokes(category));
            }


        }

        private static void getCategories()
        {
            new JsonFeed("https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/categories", 0);
            foreach (string category in JsonFeed.GetCategories())
                listofcategories.Add(category);
        }
    }

}
```

Other Classes used

```
public class ConsolePrinter
    {
        public static object PrintValue;

        public ConsolePrinter Value(string value)
        {
            PrintValue = value;
            return this;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(PrintValue);
            return null;
        }
    }
    public class Jokes
    {
        public List<string> categories { get; set; }
        public string created_at { get; set; }
        public string icon_url { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string updated_at { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }
    }
    class JsonFeed
    {
        static string _url = "";

        public JsonFeed() { }
        public JsonFeed(string endpoint, int results)
        {
            _url = endpoint;
        }

        public static string GetRandomJokes(string category)
        {

            string joke = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(_url);
                string url = string.Empty;
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(category))
                {
                    url += "?";
                    url += "category=";
                    url += category;
                }

                string respose = Task.FromResult(client.GetStringAsync(url).Result).Result;
                Jokes jokes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Jokes>(respose);
                joke = jokes.value + "" + "JokeData" + jokes.id;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.Message.ToString();
            }
            return joke;
        }

        public static List<string> GetCategories()
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            string[] response = new string[] { Task.FromResult(client.GetStringAsync(new Uri(_url)).Result).Result };

            return response.ToList();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

There is a *lot* that can be done better: it's clear that you are a beginner, so I've tried to expand on some of the fundamentales, and neglected some more advanced concerns. Feel free to ask in the comments if you want anything clarified. I expect you won't be able to internalise all of this at once, so maybe pick one aspect to focus on at a time.

#### Readability

Your `Main` method is pretty unreadable: you have a loop, nested reads, duplicate ifs conditions, and all sorts that makes it impossible to know where any part fits into the whole. Break it out into separate well-named methods, so that each part has a clear purpose, and there is minimal vertical-separation between related concerns.

It is, for instance, impossible to judge at a glance how the code exits from the `while (true)` loop (the truth being that it does not). The inner-most ifs seem to run the same thing twice if you don't have a category, but it's really confusing so I'm not certain what it's doing. Without thinking too hard, I'd say you should have:

- A method to handle reading the category from the user.
- A method to handle reading the number of jokes from the user.
- A method that takes both a category and number of jokes and retrieves and presents the jokes.
- A method to tie these together that handles the 'switching' between functions, which can be called from the `while` loop of the `Main` method

The idea is that each function should have a clear purpose, with obvious inputs and outputs. This last method, for example, should show clearly the flow of user interactions: it should not be polluted with logic for requested/presenting data from the web API.

A little more white-space would help to break up other parts of the program. It's usual to have white-space between types and methods. In other parts of the code, you have random white space that just looks untidy (in the `foreach` of `PrintCategories`).

You should be consistent with your use of braces. Most people would request you always include them (the other `foreach` of `PrintCategories`).

#### Scoping

It looks like you are not familiar with how to use objects effectively, and that you haven't had it drilled into you that variables should exist only within their meaningful scope.

`Program.category`, for example, should not be static: it should be a local variable of `Program.Main`. You don't appear to have accounted for the possibility of a user specificing a category when they requests one set of jokes, then *not* specifying a category next time around: keeping the scope of `category` tight would have made this bug impossible.

With `new JsonFeed`, you are using a constructor to initialise static variables: don't ever do this. If something needs initialising, then it's much better to initialise an instance variable and have a reusable `JsonFeed` object (i.e. make everything in `JsonFeed` non-static, and then use the instance your are creating to call the methods therein).

With this approach, your code would look like

```
var jsonFeed = new JsonFeed(...);
var response = jsonFeed.GetWhatever(...);
```

The advantages of this approach are numerous:

- It's impossible to use an uninitialised `JsonFeed` (at the moment, your static implementation 'defaults' to having an empty endpoint, which makes no sense).
- You can have more than one `JsonFeed`, each working a different endpoint (so you don't have to re-initialise the static on every time you call into a different API).
- The `JsonFeed` can be immutable, which reduces opportunities for error.
- It allows you to decouple the initialisation of the `JsonFeed` from the usage (which can be important for testing)

Static fields like `results`, `key`, etc. should not be fields at all: they should exist only within the methods that use them. `key` is very confusing, because it's meaning changes continually: if you were to swap the `c` and `r` blocks - for whatever reason - the code would stop working because the `r` block repurposes the same variable. Breaking up the `Main` method into smaller methods will help with this considerably. `results` is even worse: it's purposes and effecive data-format change within the same scope.

`getCategories` would be much nicer if it just returned a list of categories, instead of filling the existing list: again it's just confusing, because any code that needs to interrogate `categories` can't know what state it is in.

`printer.Value("Press c to get categories").ToString();` is another unhelpful API: you calling an instance method on a stateless instance which assigns a static variable which you then dispatch to the console with an *override* of `ToString` that *returns `null`*: this is extremely convoluted and generally unpleasant. It would be much better to just use `Console.WriteLine` instead, or if you wanted to pass around a printer (which is often reasonable, as you may e.g. want to use the same code again in a non-console application, but not really applicable here as you are reading from the console as well as writing to it), you could use a `TextWriter`, extracting `System.Console.Out` at the start of the application.

Do not overload `ToString` to do anything other than provide a clear representation of the object. It should never return `null`, and it should never have side-effects (e.g. printing to the console); it should just assemble and return a `string`

`iscorrect` *is* nicely scoped; however, its usage in general is messy, and it might be better to dispense with it altogether, writing, e.g.

```
string category = Console.ReadLine();
while (!listofcategoriesactaul.Contains(category))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Category \"{category}\" does not exists: please enter a category from the list");
    category = Console.ReadLine();
}

// do whatever you need to do with category
```

#### Data Representation

Your means of communicating the joke data out of `JsonFeed.GetRandomJokes` is less than ideal. You have a nice, nominal type, `Jokes`, but you are decomposing it and assembling it into an untyped string with a bizarre delimeter: don't do this; either return `Jokes` directly, or - if you don't like the naming in it (which is not typical for C#, though NewtonSoft may let you change that without issue) - extract the bits you actually want and put them into another, nice, nominal type. Something simple like this would be ideal:

```
public record Joke(string Value, string Id);
```

*`record` is (somewhat) recently introduced syntax that lets you declare a simple immutable classes concisely. Read more: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record*

Further, `Program.GetRandomJokes` should be returning a sequence of Jokes: stuffing the weird string into a static list is singularly confusing, forcing you micro-manage the `result` collection, clearing it, and rebuilding it, and all sorts. Make a new list inside `GetRandomJokes`, and return that directly.

At present, the logic for processing the weird output of `GetRandomJokes` is duplicated 3 times: normally this would suggests it should be moved into it's own method, but in this case, it should become trivial once the API is sorted out, and you don't have to mess around with the `results` list.

#### Naming

There are a few issues with your naming:

- You are inconsistent in your capitalising, e.g. `getCategories` vs `PrintCategories`.
- You should use camelCase for everything: `listofcategoriesactaul` is - spelling error aside - very hard to read because the words run into each other.
- Pairs of names like `listOfBlah` and `listOfBlahActual` is confusing: you should be processing the 'non-actual' list as soon as possible (e.g. in `getCategories`) to produce the 'actual' list, so you have just the one list where it is actually used.
- `keyValuePairs` is entirely meaningless: variables names should convay what they are being used to store *in the conext of your program*: all dictionaries can be considered a set of key-value pairs: I want to know what the keys and values themselves mean. In this case, it's a dictionary of jokes by id; using a better data-representation would help with this.
- Similarly, `number` says nothing; `count` or `numberOfJokes` would be better.
- `JsonFeed.GetRandomJokes` returns a single `Joke`; `Jokes` represents a single `Joke`; `categories` in `PrintCategories` is a single category.

Worth taking a look through the [Microsoft naming conventions for .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/general-naming-conventions).

#### Misc

- You should always removed commented out code: it creates confusion and frustration to have bits of commented out code lying around.
- `ex.Message.ToString();` doesn't do anything. You are swallowing the exception and returning a nonsense result: when a method can't do it's job, it should throw an exception; your current code 'pretends' that it worked, but is returning a nonsense result that will just cause issues elsewhere, and those issues may be hard to debug because the code may keep running for some time before it crashes, diverting the programmers attention from what caused the probably in the first place. (Again, tighter scope would help with this: if you only delcared `joke` once you have the information to construct it then there would be no tempation to return it outside the `try...catch` where it is necessarily meaningless).
- You should consider making the request logic (and `Main`) `async`, as you are using `async` methods to make the HTTP requests. Stuff like `Task.FromResult(client.GetStringAsync(url).Result).Result;` suggests you don't know how to use `async`, so best you read-up on that (I won't try to explain it here).
- It really doesn't matter for a small program like this, but you may wish to review the guidelines on how to use [`HttpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/networking/http/httpclient-guidelines#recommended-use).
- Empty blocks (e.g. after `if (listofcategoriesactaul.Contains(category))`) look like mistakes: use a negative condition, so that you can put the code under the `if`.
- The `+ ""` in `jokes.value + "" + "JokeData"` doesn't do anything; generally, `+""` is an old trick in code golf, but has no place in real code. Consider using a string interpolation to assemble such strings when you actually need them, e.g. `$"{jokes.value}JokeData{jokes.id}`.
- The `int results` parameter in the `JsonFeed` constructor is unused: delete it (your IDE should warn you about this).
- `String.Split` has an override that just takes a `String` (and a default set of options): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-7.0#system-string-split(system-string-system-stringsplitoptions)
- You have a dedicated code-path for retrieving categories, but proceed to retrieve them anyway when you request a joke: this isn't necessarily a problem, but consider that you are making a lot of extra HTTP requests: perhaps you can request the categories *once* and reuse the collection. HTTP requests may be slow or fail, none of which is good for the user experiance.
- You have an unused (parameterless) constructor in `JsonFeed`.
- `listofcategories` is a list, but you only ever consume the first value in it
- `.Replace('"', ' ').Trim()` is performed twice in `PrintCategories`.
- You should use `Match.Value` rather than `Match.ToString()`.
- You haven't implemented `?` to list the instructions; `printer.Value("Press ? to get instructions.");` also doesn't print the message about it, because you forgot the `.ToString()` because the API is so confusing.
- There is no way to cleanly exit the program.
- You never clear `listofcategoriesactaul`, so it will grow every time you go around the loop.

Comment: That was thorough. I will consider all the above recommendations :)  Coming to design pattern to use. Do you think states design pattern with switch makes sense for the above code? or is there a better way to approach the code.

Comment: @TheChosenOne94 re. State Pattern, probably not: you are implementing a simple user-interaction: trying to apply the pattern won't give you anything useful, and the additional abstraction may well make the code harder to understand. Much better to just keep the user-interaction simple by moving complex behaviours into their own methods.